# why do i get undefined in the console in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, api, asynchronous

I have create a class call weather which fetch weather data from an API ( i am using openWeather to get my weather data). Also i have created an app.js method in a different file which output the weather data on to the console.

But when ever i run the program it gives me an error message saying **undefined** in the console, precisely in (app.js). 
I am using javascript promise and async function.

Please Help! Thanks!

```
//This is the weather class

    class Weather {
    constructor (city){
        this.apiKey = '59fdf0cfa3f226ec087ef1dec6a1755a';
        this.city = city
       // this.state = state
    }
    //fetch weather from API
    async getWeather(){
        const response = await fetch (`https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?
        q=${this.city},uk&appid=${this.apiKey}.json`);

        const responseData = await response.json();

        return responseData.current_observation;
    }
    //Change weather location

    changeLocation(city,state){
        this.city = city;
        this.state = state;
    }
}
```

this is the app.js method

```
    const weather = new Weather('london');
     weather.getWeather()
    .then(results => {
       console.log(results); //this is where i get the undefined error message in the console.
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

Comment: If data is retriving from API then try with: .then(results => {
       if(results)
{
       console.log(results); //this is where i get the undefined error message in the console.
    }})

Comment: The response does not appear to have a `current_observation` property. There are no actual problems in your code, other than that the property you're trying to access doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Two issues:

1. When copy and pasted, your query had a bunch of extra spaces after the question mark and before the letter **"q"**, don't know if that is how you're running your code too. If you're using template literals, the backticks **`**, and you're moving onto the next line, that would be a problem.
2. You don't want to get the non-existent property `current_observation` you want to get `weather` or `weather[0]` as this property contains the data for the weather.

Fixing both of these should stop you from getting `undefined` in your `console.log`

Comment: when i remove "current_observation"  from the code it gives me this error  ( error: "404") in the console.

Comment: i am getting `(error : "404" )` in the console after commenting out "current_observation"  from the code. @chbchb55

Comment: Well, no part of the request has changed, are you sure your API request was ever working?

Comment: The API request works fine for me as well, don't know where the 404 might have come from

Comment: thanks you so much @chbch55 it now works , my problem was with the template literals and as i was moving to the next line. Thanks again!

Comment: @WilfredLabue if it worked for you would you mind marking it as the answer

Comment: @chbch55 , How i wish i can but i don't have enough reputation to vote it as an answer. I am still new to stackoverflow.

Comment: I don't think you need reputation to mark it as an answer, I'm not saying upvote, just mark as amswer

Comment: Ok i got what you are saying now. I have mark it as the answer.